# How to flag or separate data based on a condition within an ID variable sas

Tags: sas

I would like to pick values within an ID variable which are 10% of each other. 
For example, my data looks like this:

```
ID      Var1  
001     100  
001     109  
001     200  
001     210  
001     220  
001     300  
001     310  
002     500     
002     510
```

My desired output is some way to flag this so that I can separate this into groups:

```
ID      Var1   Flag    
001     100    1   
001     109    1      
001     200    2  
001     210    2     
001     220    2    
001     300    3   
001     310    3  
002     500    1  
002     510    1
```

I tried using a lag function and flagging data but it only flags the second row in a pair; I am not able to pull both the values in a pair that are within 10 percent of each other.

Comment: Google "processing by-groups" in SAS.  You can initialize the flag at the start of each new id.

Comment: Hi Jeff, your right about intializing it.But my challenge is to assign the flag to both the rows involved .I am only able to flag the 2nd row.For example if I consider rows 1 and 2 my condition is if diff between var1 and lag(var1) is less than 10% then flag=1 in that case it only assigns a flag to record 2 with var1=109

Comment: Don't you always want a Flag=1 at the first observation of a new Id?  If so, you don't need to lag() logic on that row -- just: if first.id then flag=1;

Comment: You should post the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to flag if the difference between records are within 10% of each other. You can determine the 10% ratio by dividing the numbers, subtracting 1 and taking the absolute value. This assumes your data is sorted by ID and ascending var1 value.

```
data want; 
set have;
by ID;
retain group;
lagv1=lag(var1);

if first.id then do;
    lagv1=.;
    group=1;
end;
else do;
    diff = abs(var1/lagv1-1);
    if diff >0.1 then group+1;
end;
run;
```